# Jersey request body needs to be well formatted

Tags: java, jackson, jersey-client

I have a requirement, where my consumer needs the request to have a well-formed request body.

I am using `Jersey Client` and below is the code snippet:

```
SomeRequestObject vSomeRequestObject = getObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT).readValue(messageBody,
                            SomeRequestObject.class);

return restClient.target(urlMap.get("uri")).path(urlMap.get("path")).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .headers(vRequestHeaders).post(Entity.entity(vSomeRequestObject, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

But somehow the request is still like this :

```
{"someKey1":"SomeValue1","someKey2":"SomeValue2"}
```

it should be like below

```
{
    "someKey1": "SomeValue1",
    "someKey2": "SomeValue2"
}
```

Please suggest if there is any jackson annotation to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You have to prettify your output. `Jackson` is able to do it with the `writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()` method.
This example below could help :

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
SomeRequestObject object = SomeRequestObject.create();
String json = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(object);
System.out.println(json);
```

This link can help you for more details : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pretty-print-json-using-jackson-library-in-java

Comment: No, I do not have to prettify the output, requirement is to prettify the input to a http call. The being called, third party needs it that way. The way object is getting set in the request is all word Wrapped with no spaces.

Comment: You can prettify the your `json` in a temporary variable, and send it after. In your case, you will store it as a `String`. Just a point to mention; your third party don't have to force you to send them a prettify `json`. The purpose of a `json` record is not be prettyfied, it just have to be a valid `json`. Prettifying a `json` is just for reading or to be displayed in a Client (UI, Web etc...)

Comment: I think your idea is correct, the alternative could be manipulate the original json with string methods but it seems me more complicated.

Comment: `Jackson` library most of the job for you. You don't really have to manipulate your `json`more than that.